# Using aplay to play a sound through subprocess within a python script

Tags: python, audio, subprocess

There are alot of libraries to play audio within a python script, I was wondering if it would be possible to simply use call aplay through the subprocess feature to play a sound? When I try it I get `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory` but there is definitely a sound there, it works when I do it through the command prompt. I may be doing something wrong as far as syntax in the python script?

```
from subprocess import call
call(["aplay /home/pi/file.wav"])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax that will work is :

```
from subprocess import call
call(["aplay", "/home/pi/file.wav"])
```

Comment: Thanks @PRMoureu! this now plays the audio, from what I was reading it must be because of having to escape the space? I will be able to accept as answer in 3 mins

Comment: @Jeff i often have trouble with string argument, can't tell if its the space, or the `-`before options, can you share the link you've found ?

Comment: Sure thing, it was the second question down mentioning escaping spaces, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python#89243 They did the comma thing like you suggested in the accepted answer too but I didn't think it would was needed, but now I see it is.

Answer (score 0):

I found that installing

`alsa-utils`

in this case : `sudo apt install alsa-utils`
make it work.

example of "text to speech"

`import pyttsx3`

**# init function to get an engine instance**

`engine = pyttsx3.init()`

**# say method for input text to be spoken**

`engine.say('Here the message you want you hear')`

**# run and wait method, it processes the voice commands.**

`engine.runAndWait()`

*I hope it helps.*